# Private method visibility confusion

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am confused with Groovy method visibility in the context of my Gradle build.
For some tests in my project, I have to first start a server. 
For this I created a custom task class that extends Gradle's `Test` like so:

```
class TestWithServer extends Test {
    TestWithServer() {
        super()
        beforeTest {
            startServer()
        }
    }
    private void startServer() {
        println('placeholder')
    }
}
```

But if I try to run such a task, I get an error:

```
Could not find method startServer() for arguments [] on task ':testWithServer' of type TestWithServer.
```

I found that when I change the visibility of `startServer()` to the default (public), the task runs fine.
How come I can't use the private method from within its own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same class, because Gradle adds some magic to the task types. Just add `println this.class` into the `beforeTest` closure to see the name of the actual class (something like `TestWithServer_Decorated`). This additional magic also explains why the error message contains the task name and how the class knows about being a task (type) at all. Since the decorated class is a subclass of your class you can use the `protected` modifier to encapsulate your method.